# im making a simple clock which have two buttons 1st for 12 hour format and 2nd for 24 hour format but button wont work when one button is working :JS

Tags: javascript, html

NOTE-I'm new to JS and in this code, 24 hour clock runs and when I tap on 12 hour clock format
button it won't replace with 24 hour clock format. basically the button wont work or it wont
replace the clock format plz help

I used a window. Onload function which runs the 24 hour format clock and when I tap on 12 hour format clock button it wont replace

just run the code u'll understand what I mean

the only thing I want to achieve in this code is a clock which have two button 1st:12 hour format 2nd:24 hour format,
to change clock format on a tap

```js
window.onload = (event) => {
  clock_24();
};

function clock_24() {
  let a;
  let date;
  let time;
  const options = {
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    year: 'numeric'
  };
  setInterval(() => {
    a = new Date();
    date = a.toLocaleDateString(undefined, options);
    let hours = String(a.getHours()).padStart(2, '0');
    let min = String(a.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
    let sec = String(a.getSeconds()).padStart(2, '0');
    let milli = a.getMilliseconds();
    time = hours + ':' + min + ':' + sec + ':' + milli;
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date
  }, 1);


  // foramt-change
  document.getElementById("format").innerHTML = "24 Hour format";
  document.getElementById("format").style.fontSize = "32px";
  document.getElementById("format").style.fontfamily = 'Times New Roman';
  console.log('24_loaded');
}


// onclick - event-12-hour-format-clock
// time-12f
function clock_12() {

  setInterval(() => {
    var date = new Date();
    var hh_12 = date.getHours() > 12 ? date.getHours() - 12 : date.getHours();
    var session_12 = date.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
    hh_12 = hh_12 < 10 ? "0" + hh_12 : hh_12;
    var mm_12 = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
    var ss_12 = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();
    tt_12 = hh_12 + ":" + mm_12 + ":" + ss_12 + " " + session_12;
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = tt_12
    // date-12f
    const options = {
      day: 'numeric',
      month: 'long',
      year: 'numeric'
    };
    date = date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, options);
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date
  }, 1000);



  // foramt-change
  document.getElementById("format").innerHTML = "12 Hour format";
  document.getElementById("format").style.fontSize = "32px";
  document.getElementById("format").style.fontfamily = 'Times New Roman';
  console.log('12_loaded');
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.t-d-cont {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
}

#format {
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(70, 166, 239);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.redline {
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.time-box {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#time {
  font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
  font-size: 45px;
}

.date-box {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#date {
  font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
  font-size: 45px;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn-2 {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- font link -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rokkitt:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- time and date container  -->
  <div class="t-d-cont">
    <div id="format">
      <h1>24 Hour format</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="redline ">
      <div class="time-box">
        <h1>Current Time: <span id="time"></span></h1>

      </div>
      <div class="date-box">
        <h1> Today's Date: <span id="date"></span></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- 24 hour-button -->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn-2" onclick="clock_24();">24-hour-format</button>
    </div>
    <!-- 12 hour-button -->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" onclick="clock_12();">12-hour-format</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>


</div>


</html>
```

Comment: The buttons are working. But your code could use a little trimming because you are repeating yourself. Also the intervals are interfering each other. I would suggest the 24/12 status to be in a global variable. Then use one function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you switch the clocks, you need to stop the interval timer that's displaying using the previous format. Otherwise they both keep running, and one will overwrite the other.

Use a variable outside the functions to hold the current interval timer ID, so you can stop it with `clearInterval()`.

```js
window.onload = (event) => {
  clock_24();
};

let timer;

function clock_24() {
  let a;
  let date;
  let time;
  const options = {
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    year: 'numeric'
  };
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(() => {
    a = new Date();
    date = a.toLocaleDateString(undefined, options);
    let hours = String(a.getHours()).padStart(2, '0');
    let min = String(a.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
    let sec = String(a.getSeconds()).padStart(2, '0');
    let milli = a.getMilliseconds();
    time = hours + ':' + min + ':' + sec + ':' + milli;
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date
  }, 1);


  // foramt-change
  document.getElementById("format").innerHTML = "24 Hour format";
  document.getElementById("format").style.fontSize = "32px";
  document.getElementById("format").style.fontfamily = 'Times New Roman';
  console.log('24_loaded');
}


// onclick - event-12-hour-format-clock
// time-12f
function clock_12() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(() => {
    var date = new Date();
    var hh_12 = date.getHours() > 12 ? date.getHours() - 12 : date.getHours();
    var session_12 = date.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
    hh_12 = hh_12 < 10 ? "0" + hh_12 : hh_12;
    var mm_12 = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
    var ss_12 = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();
    tt_12 = hh_12 + ":" + mm_12 + ":" + ss_12 + " " + session_12;
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = tt_12
    // date-12f
    const options = {
      day: 'numeric',
      month: 'long',
      year: 'numeric'
    };
    date = date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, options);
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date
  }, 1000);



  // foramt-change
  document.getElementById("format").innerHTML = "12 Hour format";
  document.getElementById("format").style.fontSize = "32px";
  document.getElementById("format").style.fontfamily = 'Times New Roman';
  console.log('12_loaded');
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.t-d-cont {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
}

#format {
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(70, 166, 239);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.redline {
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.time-box {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#time {
  font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
  font-size: 45px;
}

.date-box {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#date {
  font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
  font-size: 45px;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn-2 {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- font link -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rokkitt:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- time and date container  -->
  <div class="t-d-cont">
    <div id="format">
      <h1>24 Hour format</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="redline ">
      <div class="time-box">
        <h1>Current Time: <span id="time"></span></h1>

      </div>
      <div class="date-box">
        <h1> Today's Date: <span id="date"></span></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- 24 hour-button -->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn-2" onclick="clock_24();">24-hour-format</button>
    </div>
    <!-- 12 hour-button -->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" onclick="clock_12();">12-hour-format</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>


</div>


</html>
```